# How to send array data as input in GraphQL query?

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I'm learning GraphQL and for practice purpose I have developed a backend that would create a planner with the following inputs, tasks which is an array of type Task, dayDescription and waterGlassCount which are Strings. I'm getting issues in TypeDefinition.js where I have created an input with Tasks having the type [Task]. Please have a look at my TypeDefinition.js

```
const {gql} = require('apollo-server-express')

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Planner{
    id: ID
    tasks: [Task]
    dayDescription: String
    waterGlassCount: String
  }
  type Task{
    id: ID
    taskDescription: String
    shouldStrike: Boolean
  }
  type Query {
    getAllPlanners: [Planner]
    getPlanner(id:ID): Planner
    getAllTasksOfPlanner(id:ID): [Task]
    getEachTaskOfTasksOfPlanner(id: ID): Task
  }
  input TaskInput{
    taskDescription: String
    shouldStrike: Boolean
  }
  input PlannerInput{
    tasks: [Task]
    dayDescription: String
    waterGlassCount: String
  }
  type Mutation {
    createPlanner(planner: PlannerInput) : Planner
    createTask(task: TaskInput): Task
    deletePlanner(id:ID): String
    deleteAllPlanners : String
    toggleStrike(id:ID): Task
    updatePlanner(id:ID, planner: PlannerInput): Planner
    deleteAllTasks(id:ID): String   
  }
`;
module.exports=typeDefs;
```

This is the code of Resolvers.js.

```
const Planner = require('./Models/PlannerModel');
const Task = require('./Models/TasksModel')

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      getAllPlanners: async ()=>{
        return await Planner.find()
      },
      getPlanner: async(parent, {id}, context, info)=> {
        return await Planner.findById(id)
      },
      getAllTasksOfPlanner: async (parent, {id}, context, info) => {
        const planner = await Planner.findById(id);
        return planner.tasks
      },
      getEachTaskOfTasksOfPlanner: async (parent, {id}, context, info) => {
        return await Task.findById(id)
      },
    },
    Mutation:{
      createPlanner: async(parent, args, context, info)=>{
        const { dayDescription, waterGlassCount} = args.planner
        const planner = new Planner({ dayDescription, waterGlassCount})
        await planner.save()
        return planner
      },
      createTask : async(parent, {taskDescription, shouldStrike}, context, info) => {
        const task = new Task({taskDescription, shouldStrike})
        await task.save();
        return task
      },
      deletePlanner: async (parent, {id}, context, info) => {
        await Planner.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        return 'Planner Deleted'
      },
      deleteAllPlanners: async() => {      
        await Planner.deleteMany({})
      },
      toggleStrike : async (parent, {id}, context, info) =>{
        const task = await Task.findById(id);
        task.shouldStrike = !task.shouldStrike
        return task
      },
      updatePlanner: async(parent, args, context, info)=>{
        const {id}= args;
        const {tasks, dayDescription, waterGlassCount} = args.planner;
        const updates ={};
        if(tasks !== undefined){
          updates.tasks = tasks
        }
        if(dayDescription!== undefined){
          updates.dayDescription = dayDescription
        }
        if(waterGlassCount !== undefined){
          updates.waterGlassCount = waterGlassCount
        }
        const planner = Planner.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updates, {new:true});
        return planner
      },
    }
  };

  module.exports = resolvers;
```

The following is the code for PlannerModel and TaskModel

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PlannerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  tasks: {
    type: Array,
  },
  dayDescription: {
    type: String,
  },
  waterGlassCount: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const Planner = mongoose.model("planner", PlannerSchema);

module.exports = Planner;
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  taskDescription: {
    type: String,
  },
  shouldStrike:{
    type: Boolean
  }
});

const Task = mongoose.model("task", TaskSchema);

module.exports = Task;
```

The error I get in the terminal is "Error: The type of PlannerInput.tasks must be Input Type but got: [Task]". How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using an `input` type, all fields inside this type must also be `input` types (or scalars). In your case `Task` is not an `input` type. Maybe it should be `TaskInput`?